# random empty <a> tags popping up on webpage and ruining spacing, not showing in page source

Tags: html

When inspecting the element, I find the following. However it is not visible in the page source code and I cant seem to find this in the back end either.

```
<a>
        <h4>Company.</h4>
        </a>

<a>
            </a>
```

(please note I did not add the  tags to the header?)

Comment: Problem solved. Facebook like button caused an issue, need to now find a work around.

Comment: Thats great news. You could possibly [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own question.

Comment: I don't think he can : "(...)If you have more than 15 reputation(...)"